# Is there a reason why Facebook PHP-SDK is using $_COOKIE instead for a $_SESSION?

Tags: facebook, session, cookies, session-cookies, facebook-javascript-sdk

This question is related with the following issue:

[Is there a way to invalidate user's cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247498/is-there-a-way-to-invalidate-users-cookie)

Comment: Facebook developers might know better.

Comment: Well, (a) I've tagged this as a Facebook question, (b) other people are welcome to provide technical explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Session works for your server only. You can use $_SESSION variable just to store data within your server. But as when you perform authentication with facebook they can not set any variable in your server's $_SESSION variable so they use cookies to store data on browser from where your script can pick it.